# Unable to match the first word from a file using Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, file

I am trying to match words from array to create a Symbol Table for Lexical Analysis (compiler lab). I am reading a C code file from Java. I am able to find everything from the file except the first word. No matter what I try the first word does not match with anything although it is a valid word. 
In my file, the first word is int (initialization of two variable) and second line is float (initialization). If I swap it, my code can match int but did not match float.

here is the file I am reading:

```
float d, e;
int a, b, c;
```

Here is the code to read from file:

```
public static void fileRead(String fileName)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            String x;
            while ( (x = br.readLine()) != null ) 
            {
                // printing out each line in the file
                System.out.println(x);
                parser(x);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

parser is another method and it is used to parse out different words:

```
public static void parser(String line)
{
    String text = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        String temp = line.charAt(i) + "";


        if(!(temp.equals(" ") 
                || temp.equals(",") 
                || temp.equals(";")
                || temp.equals(")")
                || temp.equals("}")
                || temp.equals("(")
                || temp.equals("{")
                || temp.equals("[")
                || temp.equals("]")
                ))
        {
            text = text + temp;
        }
        else
        {
            text = text.trim();
            if(text.equals("int"))
            {
                System.out.println("Say cheese");
            }
            addToarray(text);
            text = "";
}
}
```

I thought there might a space at the end so I trimmed it as well as backup.

and this is how I am adding to an array:
if(item.equals(text))
Here the "int" seemed to lose and never went inside the if block

```
public static void addToarray(String text)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    //look for keyWords first.
    for (String item : keyWords) 
    {
        if(item.equals(text))
        {
            if(resultKey.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Size zero> "+resultKey.size());
                resultKey.add(text);
                text = "";
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                boolean checker = true;
                for(String key : resultKey)
                {
                    if(key.equals(text))
                    {
                        checker = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(checker)
                {
                    resultKey.add(text);
                    flag = true;
                    text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the array I am using to match:

```
final static String []keyWords = {"float", "if", "else", 
    "long", "double", "BigInteger","int"};
```

and these are the ArrayList to store variables.

```
 static ArrayList <String> resultKey, resultIdent , resultMath, 
resultLogic, resultNumeric, resultOthers;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: At what part of your code do you lose track of the word for the first time ?

Comment: Gosh, please: StringBuilder, Set - use them! :) `text="";` is completely senseless. Maybe then you'll have enough clarity in the code to find the bug.

Comment: I solved this problem hardcodedly :p by adding an extra line at the top of the file. @Berger, I have pointed the point of bug

Comment: Could it be that there is a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of the file? You wouldn't see it without Hex-Editor and it will result in the first word starting with some bytes you do not expect.

Comment: I'm missing the `resultKey` variable. What is it?

Comment: @Fildor, how to see whether I have BOM at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis, resultKey is my result arrayList. I have reedited the question.

Comment: @Ibtehaz Monkey use an InputStreamReader and get the value of the first byte , by calling _read()_ once.

Comment: Take a HexEditor (for example Notepad++ with Hex-Addon) and open the file. If there are some bytes before the "i" of "int" - that's your BOM. Some Editors also can "show unprintable chars" or even detect BOM.

Comment: okay thanks :) I will check it out.

Comment: How did you create the file? Try another editor.

Comment: You shouldn't parse a file by reading it with readlines.  It s prone to memory exhaustion failure.  Use a buffered read instead.

Comment: @Fildor, I did not create this file. Its been provided to me.

Comment: See this: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php There is a section on how to detect the BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Lauching this simple app it works, <strike>don't know why you are unable to read the first word.</strike> **EDIT**: 100% it's the starting BOM in your file as @Fildor noticed.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parser {

    final static String[] keyWords = { "float", "if", "else", "long", "double", "BigInteger", "int" };
    static ArrayList<String> resultKey = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fileRead("src/test/resources/test.txt");
        for (final String key : resultKey) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

    public static void fileRead(String fileName) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            try {
                String x;
                while ((x = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    // printing out each line in the file
                    System.out.println(x);
                    parser(x);
                }

                br.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void parser(String line) {
        String text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            final String temp = line.charAt(i) + "";

            if (!(temp.equals(" ") || temp.equals(",") || temp.equals(";") || temp.equals(")") || temp.equals("}")
                    || temp.equals("(") || temp.equals("{") || temp.equals("[") || temp.equals("]"))) {
                text = text + temp;
            } else {
                text = text.trim();
                if (text.equals("int")) {
                    System.out.println("Say cheese");
                }
                addToarray(text);
                text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addToarray(String text) {
        boolean flag = false;
        // look for keyWords first.
        for (final String item : keyWords) {
            if (item.equals(text)) {
                if (resultKey.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Size zero> " + resultKey.size());
                    resultKey.add(text);
                    text = "";
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean checker = true;
                    for (final String key : resultKey) {
                        if (key.equals(text)) {
                            checker = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (checker) {
                        resultKey.add(text);
                        flag = true;
                        text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the file `test.txt` contains exactly

```
float d, e;
int a, b, c;
```

Launching it prints

```
float d, e;
Size zero> 0
int a, b, c;
Say cheese
float
int
```

Comment: I know: It's a BOM inside his input file.

Answer (score 0):

"int" is not matched, because your input file probably contains a Byte-Order-Mark.

You can check for it in code or with a Hex-Editor. Most likely it will be one of 0xEFBBBF (UTF-8) , 0xFEFF (UTF-16 Big Endian) or 0xFFFE (UTF-16 Little Endian). But there are more. I already referenced a W3C-Document on the topic in the comments. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is the Wikipedia-Article with even more BOMs.

Sidenote:

Which teacher hands out a "dirty" input file!? He must be some kind of sadist or (which would be even worse, imho) he did not do it on purpose. I would try to copy the (printable) content of the file to a new file and test this as input. So if the clean file works to your satisfaction, you can find some means of sanitizing input.